# If the name of the main file in my project is changed from main.py to something else, will it make any difference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm, project

If I change the name of the main python file in my project directory from main.py, will it make any difference? For example, if a project of mine has an image and two scripts main.py and side.py, and if I rename main.py to myfile.py, will it impact my project in any way? If so, how?
I don't think this is a duplicate since I researched a lot before asking. Sorry if I sound like an idiot, I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to any function (e.g. function1, function2) in myfile.py from side.py, pl change your import in side.py to  `from myfile import function1,function2.`

Answer (score 0):

If you import anything from your main.py to your side.py then you will get errors.
So after renaming main.py to main2.py (for example), change

```
from . import main
```

to

```
from . import main2
```

What i mean is rename main.py imports.
Otherwise don't do anything the program will just work fine.

Comment: I am not importing main.py into side.py, I'm importing side.py into main.py